# Blue Color Arrow in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have pressed some key and blue color arrow is appearing on left hand side of visual studio 2010 and i am not able to see how to remove it or disable it.

Please see the attached image.

[image: Blue Color arrow on left hand side in VS 2010]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a task list icon. You may have added it, or it may have been automatically added by the editor (for example to mark lines with 'TODO' comments).

Similar to a bookmark, it allows you to jump through items marked by it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4efffwe%28v=vs.80%29.aspx